# Jenkins build fails every odd build

Tags: ansible, jenkins

So I've recently ran into weird problem, my jenkins build fails every odd build for no reason. Build is simple, it runs ansible playbook which in turns deploys code to remote machines, clears caches, runs maintenance, etc.

[image: Fails every odd build]

Build basically runs this:

```
ansible-playbook -i ansible/hosts ansible/backend.yml
```

Then, when the build number is odd, it fails on this step(runs with force=yes so local modifications should be no problem):

```
TASK [backend : Clone backend repo] ********************************************
task path: /opt/provision/ansible/roles/backend/tasks/main.yml:5
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/source_control/git.py
<server_ip_address> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: username
<server_ip_address> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/jenkins"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ConnectionAttempts=20 -o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r server_ip_address '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<server_ip_address> PUT /tmp/tmpdgsmCK TO /home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499/git.py
<server_ip_address> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/jenkins"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ConnectionAttempts=20 -o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[server_ip_address]'
<server_ip_address> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: username
<server_ip_address> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/jenkins"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ConnectionAttempts=20 -o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r server_ip_address '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499/ /home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499/git.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<server_ip_address> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: username
<server_ip_address> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/jenkins"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ConnectionAttempts=20 -o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt server_ip_address '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python /home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499/git.py; rm -rf "/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485853855.83-181127458563499/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
fatal: [backend]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "git"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 23456\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\nShared connection to server_ip_address closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_lVW4UB/ansible_module_git.py\", line 1040, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_lVW4UB/ansible_module_git.py\", line 994, in main\r\n    result.update(changed=True, after=remote_head, msg='Local modifications exist')\r\nUnboundLocalError: local variable 'remote_head' referenced before assignment\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/opt/provision/ansible/backend.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
backend                       : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Traceback formated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lVW4UB/ansible_module_git.py\", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lVW4UB/ansible_module_git.py\", line 994, in main
    result.update(changed=True, after=remote_head, msg='Local modifications exist')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'remote_head' referenced before assignment
```

Failing step:

```
- name: Clone backend 
  git: >
   repo="{{ backend_repo }}"
   dest="{{ backend_path }}"
   accept_hostkey=yes
   key_file="{{ backend_key }}"
   clone=yes
   force=yes
   update=yes
   version={{ backend_branch }}
```

If you run build immediately after it fails, it builds nicely. Also it builds every time I run it from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'remote_head' referenced before assignment

I suspect you hit a bug, that was [fixed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/19057) in Ansible 2.2.1. Please update.

Comment: Tried that, still same. `remote_head` is still present in error mesage, ansible version:`$ ansible --version           
ansible 2.2.1.0                                        
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg               
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides`

Comment: please provide line number of the error, like `ansible_module_git.py\", line 994` in your OP

Comment: Yes indeed it is a bug, though it is not fixed in 2.2.1 from pip. Thread regarding this bug suggests adding next lines(naming mine) to failing git step:
`register: backend_deploy
until: backend_deploy|succeeded`